# Is it really all about message passing in Smalltalk?

Tags: smalltalk

I'm new to Smalltalk and I'm impressed with the fact that there are only just 6 keywords in the language (`self`, `super`, `true`, `false`, `nil` & `thisContext`), and how pure it is in having almost everything as message passing, eg. looping using `whileTrue`, if/else using `ifTrue`, etc ... which are way different from what I'm used to in other languages.

Yet, there are cases where I just cannot make sense of how message passing really fit in, these include:

- the assignment operator `:=`
- the cascading operator `;`
- the period operator `.`
- the way to create a set `#( ... )`

These aren't message passing, right?

Comment: +1 but how are these typically used? To me "message passing" is about how *objects* interacts with each other. If you're talking about details *inside* objects, to me it's unrelated and the point is moot:  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Message_passing   Note that even in a totally "non-pure OO language" like Java you *can* do better "message passing" than what the average Java dev will do (for example getters and setters everywhere, not realizing getters and setters are the anti-thesis of OO).

Comment: Yup, some of them really aren't message passing. But then i was thinking `:=` looks like one, eg. `x := 1 + 2` may just mean that send the colon equals message to `x`, such that it takes the value of `1+2`, but then, the precedence rule doesn't fit in.

Comment: @SyntaxT3rr0r "getters and setters are the anti-thesis of OO" Quite the reverse, surely?  Simple instance accessors defined in the object's own class are the *basis* of OO. They are the foundation-stone of encapsulation, which is what allows for loosely-coupled objects.   Many Java coders must be incorporating complex and tightly-coupled behaviours into the basic getter and setter accessor methods if getter and setters are viewed as the antithesis of OO in Java code.  Or am I missing something?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

As you've discovered, there's still some actual Smalltalk syntax. Block construction, literal strings/symbols/comments, local variable declaration (`|...|`), and returning (`^`) are a few things you didn't mention which are also syntax.

Some extensions (e.g. `#(...)`, which typically creates an `Array`, not a set) are certainly expressible otherwise, for example `#(1 2 3)` is equivalent to `Array with: 1 with: 2 with: 3`; they're just there to make the code easier to read and write.

Comment: Note that the return `^` and the assignment `:=` are also expressible using message sends: `thisContext return: anObject` and `anObject instVarNamed: 'foo' put: anObject` (for instance variables, temporaries and globals work similar).

Comment: We can almost say that `^` and `:=` are syntactic sugar ;)

Answer (score 2):

One thing that might help clarify :  `self`, `super`, `true`, `false`, `nil` & `thisContext` are data primitives, rather than keywords.

They are the only 6 data primitives. These 6 are also known as *pseudo-variables*.  Absolutely every other thing is an instance of Class Object or its subclasses.

There are very few pre-defined keywords in Smalltalk.  They can be written in a very condensed form.

A famous example is [Smalltalk Syntax on a Postcard (link)](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?SmalltalkSyntaxInaPostcard)

```
 exampleWithNumber: x

    | y |
    true & false not & (nil isNil) ifFalse: [self halt].
    y := self size + super size.
    #($a #a "a" 1 1.0)
        do: [ :each |
            Transcript show: (each class name);
                       show: ' '].
    ^x < y
```

Here's the comment for this method - which is larger than the method itself:

> "A method that illustrates every part of Smalltalk method syntax
>               except primitives. It has unary, binary, and keyboard messages,
>               declares arguments and temporaries, accesses a global variable
>               (but not an instance variable), uses literals (array, character,
>               symbol, string, integer, float), uses the pseudo variables
>               true, false, nil, self, and super, and has sequence, assignment,
>               return and cascade. It has both zero argument and one argument blocks."